# Folder icons does not appeared in Open File Dialog Box

Tags: user-interface, dialog, scheme, lisp, racket

I am trying to open files from a dialog box using these codes,

```
#lang racket/gui
(require racket/gui/base
        framework
        mrlib/path-dialog)

(define top-frame (new frame%
                   [label "The Frame"]
                   [min-width 200]
                   [min-height 100]
                   [alignment (list 'center 'center)]))
(send top-frame show #t)

(define open (new path-dialog%
                  [existing? #t]
                  [filters (list (list "My Documents" "*.docx")
                                 (list "Text Files" "*.txt"))]))

(define open-button
  (new button%
       [label "Open File"]
       [parent top-frame]
       [callback (lambda (b e)
                   (define input-port-or-not (send open run))
                   (when input-port-or-not
                     (message-box "open dialog" (format "Dialog box is open.") #f '(ok no-icon))))]))
```

And I get this Open File Dialog without folder icons

[image]

How do I change to get the appearance of the dialog box as the picture below which shows the folder icons?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible if you want to just use `mrlib/path-dialog`.

However, here's its code: https://www.apt-browse.org/browse/ubuntu/trusty/universe/all/racket-common/5.3.6%2Bdfsg1-1/file/usr/share/racket/collects/mred/private/path-dialog.rkt. By modifying this file, you might be able to get what you want.

(if you use Linux, the file can be found at `/usr/share/racket/pkgs/gui-lib/mred/private/path-dialog.rkt`)